# SSRS 2008 Column total of a textbox expression in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I working on a report using a matrix with SSRS 2008:

Here's what the report is based on:

**Groups**:

Row group: Sales Rep

Column group: Date (year/month)

**Data**:

- *Count of sales type 1*
- *Count of sales type 2*
- *Ratio (%)* of both sales types count
- *Bonus*: the bonus is based on a certain percentage of the ratio and is calculated with the textbox expression.

  ```
      Rep     Type 1      Type 2      Ratio   Bonus
      A       13          0           0       325
      B       26          2           7.7     0
      C       23          1           4.3     220
  ```

  The ratio is calculated by dividing Type 2 by Type 1.

  The bonus is calculated like this: 
  If the ratio is between 0 and 0.03, then substract Type2 from Type1 then multiply by 25
  If the ratio is less of equal than 0.04 but bigger than 0.03, then substract Type2 from Type1 then multiply by 15
  If the ratio is smaller than 0.05 but bigger than 0.04, then substract Type2 from Type1 then multiply by 10
  If the ratio is higher than 0.05 then bonus = 0

There’s a bonus total for each rep for the report’s period (months displayed on the report columns) outside the column group using a function which tallies the bonuses and resets the bonus sub total after each row.

Now, what I need to achieve is a column total of all bonuses given. Since the Bonus textbox is based on an expression, I can’t add a total (SUM) and since the bonuses are calculated for each individual sales rep and their own ratio, I can’t use the row group totals to do the calculations.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward. If you can share sample data and report design, it would be easy to answer.

Comment: Added sampled data and calculations. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the whole Ratio and Bonus calculation upstream e.g. into SQL in the Dataset.

This also has the advantage of being easier to test as you can run the SQL independantly of SSRS.

Comment: Well, it seemed easier at first doing all the calculation from within the report since it looked pretty straightforward. Now i'm thinking it won't be...

Comment: Mike, as per your suggestion, I moved everything to the dataset. Works like a charm now. Thank you.